# Incorrect format of sending mail from Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

My file format is as below：

```
cat myfile.txt

Size of user01 is  1863 MB, it over than 100 MB
Size of user02 is  1863 MB, it over than 100 MB
Size of user03 is  815 MB, it over than 100 MB
```

But if I mail it to my mailbox,

```
cat ./myfile.txt | mail -s "This is test Mail" myemail@domain.com
```

the format will be as below:

```
Size of user01 is 1863 MB, it over than 100 MB Size of user02 is 1863 MB, it over than 100 MB Size of user03 is 815 MB, it over than 100 MB
```

How can I keep my original format when I send file content to my mailbox!?

Comment: I just tried it on my system and the mail was correctly formatted. It sounds like you have an issue with the configuration of your `sendmail` or `postfix` software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SMTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-4) says that end-of-line in SMTP messages is

```
 \r\n   (return+newline)
```

where in Unix/Linux the end of line is

```
 \n  (newline)
```

Run the text though a `tr` filter to convert all the \n to \r\n -- or pipe it through `unix2dos` which does the same thing, like;

```
cat ./myfile.txt | unix2dos | mail -s "This is test Mail" myemail@domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I received the mail with attachment after installing unix2dos and tried command.
Is it possible to keep text format ?

Comment: The MTA should convert the message contents from Unix format to SMTP format. It's not necessary to do that before piping to `mail`.

Comment: @Soren I would like to thanks you again for your presentation.
I tried some test:
`cat myfile.txt | unix2dos | mail -s "This is test mail" myname@mydomain.com`
 But instead of receiving the content of file in the mail i got an attachment with name AT00001.bin.
And I tried Mutt
`cat size_report.txt | unix2dos | mutt -s "This is test Mail" yiweis@sparqtron.com`
This is what I want.I received the content of file
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the mail command with content type html and use html **pre** tag  to get it .

```
echo "<pre>`cat myfile.txt`</pre>" | mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "This is test Mail" myemail@domain.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.
I tried the code that you provided. But System show error message :
"Content-type: text/html: No such file or directory". If I typed
 `echo "<pre>`cat myfile.txt`</pre>" | mail -s "This is test mail" myname@mydomain.com` . I got mail that has the same format just add <pre> </pre>. Is there any typo in my code?

Comment: I think you missed the back ticks in your command. It works.